# Updating data with JDBC in MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I just started learning JDBC and databases. I was trying to create a simple code of Updating data to already existing database. I created localhost with xampp added and some data. I read some tutorials on oracle web page and watched couple of lynda.com videos about JDBC and tried to write this program, but it doesn't work.

This is my main

```
package com.lynda.javatraining.db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {

    private static final String USERNAME = "vato";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "vatopassword";
    private static final String CONN_STRING =
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost/university";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;    
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            Building something = new Building();
            something.UpdateBuilding("Daniels", "Gordon", 5, conn);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I created a Building class for having some functions to add building, Update, delete etc.

This is my code for Updatebuilding class.

```
public void UpdateBuilding(String NewName, String buildingname, int IDnum, Connection conn) throws SQLException
    {
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE building SET BuildingName = \"" + NewName + "\" WHERE BuildingID = '"+ IDnum +"' AND BuildingName = '" + buildingname + ";");
            this.PrintBuilding(conn);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

When compiling this code i get this error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Gordon' at line 1
```

I tried not to give Gordon as parameter, but then I got the same error about the ID number "5" at line 1.

Can u please help me? whats wrong with this code?

Comment: What is your built query looking like ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss an `'` at and of your statement:

```
AND BuildingName = '" + buildingname + "';");
                                        ^^^
```

This should solve your problem. But think about prepared statement. It is much better to use prepared statement.

Comment: OMG. -_- I'm so sorry for this dumb question. I tried to check for syntax error, but somehow missed it. I hate asking this kind of questions. Thanks for your answer. It Worked!

Comment: How about the double-quoted string value? It is a syntax error as well.

Comment: @PeterWiggin Why is it a syntax error? I used double-quoted because some names of the buildings might consist of two words.

Comment: ' might consist of two words ' is not a reason for using double quotes. Rather escape the values correctly and even a single quote in the word will not break the query.

Answer (score 2):

your IDnum must be a number, hence do not use ''.

Use the following :

```
stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE building SET BuildingName = '" + NewName + "' WHERE BuildingID = " + IDnum +" AND BuildingName = '" + buildingname + "';");
```

If this is usefull, mark as answer

Comment: I think Jens answered first. I have to mark his one as an answer. But I up voted your's. Thank you!

Comment: You are adding a single quotes to ur IDnum too, just have a check at it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
String sql  = "UPDATE building SET BuildingName = \"" + NewName + "\" WHERE BuildingID = '"+ IDnum +"' AND BuildingName = '" + buildingname + ";"
```

try to use PreparedStatement in proper manner
e.g.

```
 PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE building SET BuildingName = ? WHERE BuildingID = ? AND BuildingName = ?");
 pstmt.setString(1, NewName);
 pstmt.setString(2, IDnum);
 pstmt.setString(3, buildingname);
 pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just read about PreparedStatement and totally forgot about it. I'm glad you reminded me of it.